Exception in data insertion in sqflite
I'm using the sqflite package to store data locally in my mobile app. Upon testing the app on my physical android device, it's showing the following exception that I printed in a debugPrint statement:
I/flutter ( 6488): SQL INSERTION EXCEPTION: DatabaseException(near "logo": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO Preferences (co_id, default_br_id, default_wh_id, logo, business_name, business_tax_vat_id, last_sales_invoice_id, last_sales_return_invoice_id, last_purchase_invoice_id, last_purchase_return_invoice_id, last_sales_quotation_id)
I/flutter ( 6488):     VALUES (13, 1, 1, the logo, شركة الرحاب للعطور, business_tax_vat_id, null, null, null, null, null)) sql '    INSERT INTO Preferences (co_id, default_br_id, default_wh_id, logo, business_name, business_tax_vat_id, last_sales_invoice_id, last_sales_return_invoice_id, last_purchase_invoice_id, last_purchase_return_invoice_id, last_sales_quotation_id)
I/flutter ( 6488):     VALUES (13, 1, 1, the logo, شركة الرحاب للعطور, business_tax_vat_id, null, null, null, null, null)
I/flutter ( 6488):     ' args []

This is the code statement causing the exception:
await database.rawInsert("""
    INSERT INTO Preferences (co_id, default_br_id, default_wh_id, logo, business_name, business_tax_vat_id, last_sales_invoice_id, last_sales_return_invoice_id, last_purchase_invoice_id, last_purchase_return_invoice_id, last_sales_quotation_id)
    VALUES (${json['co_id']}, ${json['default_br_id']}, ${json['default_wh_id']}, ${json['logo']}, ${json['business_name']}, ${'business_tax_vat_id'}, null, null, null, null, null)
    """);

I checked the syntax many times and checked for similar issues on the internet but nothing worked.

I’m guessing you need single quotes round the string values you are trying to insert

Try this:
await database.rawInsert("""
    INSERT INTO Preferences (
        co_id, default_br_id, default_wh_id, logo, business_name, business_tax_vat_id, 
        last_sales_invoice_id, last_sales_return_invoice_id, last_purchase_invoice_id, 
        last_purchase_return_invoice_id, last_sales_quotation_id
    ) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """, [
        json['co_id'],
        json['default_br_id'],
        json['default_wh_id'],
        json['logo'],
        json['business_name'],
        json['business_tax_vat_id'],
        null, 
        null,  
        null,  
        null,  
        null   
    ]);


It worked, thanks! But the question here is why didn't my code work ?

The mistake in your query is that string values are not enclosed in single quotes. SQL requires string values to be surrounded by single quotes to differentiate them from column names and other elements. For example, if you have a value like the logo, it should be written as 'the logo'. The same applies to other string values such as business_name and business_tax_vat_id.
